# Mono not emitting items when using zipWhen operator (Java/Spring/Reactor)

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have the following methods:

```
Mono<User> doSomething1(String username) {
    return userService
                .getUser(username)
                .doOnError(error -> LOG.error(error.getMessage(), error));
  }

Mono<User> doSomething2(String username) {
    return userService
                .getUser(username)
                .zipWhen(this::processUser)
                .map(Tuple2::getT1)
                .doOnError(error -> LOG.error(error.getMessage(), error));
  }

Mono<Void> processUser(User user){
  return Mono.empty();
}
```

When I call `doSomething1("test_user")` I get a Mono with the expected user.
However when I call `doSomething2("test_user")` the Mono simply completes without emitting any `User` item. Any idea why this is?

Comment: The mono tag isn't for Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because `processUser` returns `Mono<Void>` and technically there is nothing to zip with

Here is a description of the `zipWhen`

> Wait for the result from this mono, use it to create a second mono via the provided rightGenerator function and combine both results into a Tuple2.

In your case `rightGenerator` returns `Mono.empty()` and it completes the flow.

Using `zipWhen` here is a little strange until you want to mutate `User` in `processUser`. I would rather use `flatMap` that is more natural here

```
 return userService
          .getUser(username)
          .flatMap(user -> 
                 processUser(user)
                    .thenReturn(user)
          )
```